# Is there a max lenght in Gson string to archive in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

In my Android app i archive large amount of data as json in my SharedPreferences, the json items are build as the following `{"codiceArticolo":"0401100028053","data":"mer 03/07/2019","qta":"1"}` there could be more than 500 items like this in the JSON.

Actually the json is generated from an ArrayList from the following method

```
public void saveStorico(){

    ArrayList<ItemModel> itemToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ItemModel> itemToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    // various controlls
    for(ItemModel itemModels : itemModel){
        boolean exist = false;
        for(ItemModel itemModel2 : itemStorico){
            if(itemModels.getCodiceArticolo().contains(itemModel2.getCodiceArticolo())) {
                itemToRemove.add(itemModel2);
                itemToAdd.add(itemModels);
                exist = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exist) {
            itemToAdd.add(itemModels);
        }
    }

    itemStorico.removeAll(itemToRemove);
    itemStorico.addAll(itemToAdd);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("STORICO_ORDINI", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(itemStorico);
    editor.putString("storico", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

But i'm having some issues when i fetch that data it seems that some of saved items just are not being saved, could there be a max lenght limit that i could save inside sharedpreferences as json?

Answer (score 0):

*If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.*

For large amounts of data as in your case, SharedPreferences is not a good choice.
You should rather be using a SQL database or a NoSQL database instead.

As per what I have seen before, if the shared preferences go beyond 100kb, you need to consider alternatives. And if it exceeds ~1MB, there potentially can be out of memory exceptions.

Comment: Actually i know i should store just small collection of key-values but i had no time when i've made the application and i had to implement a fastest solution for store that data, anyway 500 items stored in shared prefs doesn't takes up than 64kb...